# batch requests with credentials using React Apollo

Tags: cookies, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

How do you batch requests with credentials? I'm using an http-only JWT cookie and HttpLink allows me to pass a `credentials: 'include'` option which will forward the cookie through to my graphene server. When I try to switch to BatchHttpLink, it no longer accepts that option for configuration. Looking through the source, it doesn't appear there's an easy way to configure this. Anyone know how to handle this?

Here's how I was doing it without batching:

```
window['app-react'].GRAPHQL_URL = window['app-react'].GRAPHQL_URL || 'http://backend.app.local/graphiql'
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: window['app-react'].GRAPHQL_URL,
  credentials: 'include'
})
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
})
```

Here's how I wish it worked:

```
const batchHttpLink = new BatchHttpLink({
  uri: window['joor-react'].GRAPHQL_URL,
  credentials: 'include'
})
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: batchHttpLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
})
```

When I do it this way though, the JWT cookie isn't passed in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Right now `apollo-link-batch-http` is behind in its API compared to `apollo-link-http`. Here is a note from the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/batch-http.html) (as of 2017-12-07)

> Note: This package will be updated to remove the dependency on apollo-fetch an use the same options / API as the http-link

**Using BatchHttpLink with apollo-fetch**

The current API of `apollo-link-batch-http` requires a custom `apollo-fetch` if you want to make customizations to things like credentials. Here's a couple of options.

1. Provide a `customFetch` to `createApolloFetch` and define `credentials` in the fetch options.
2. Use apollo-fetch middleware

   ```
   fetch.batchUse(({ options }, next) => {
     options.credentials = 'include';
     next();
   });
   ```